# update mysql on debian

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to update Mysql on debian without success, and all tutorial on internet just fails.
I got Debian 6.0.6 squeeze, my mysql version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63`.
I did `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` it says that nothing is to upgrade.
So I downloaded the last version `wget --content-disposition http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/` and installed it

```
# dpkg -i mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 41264 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql 5.5.28 (using mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql ...
Setting up mysql (5.5.28) ...
```

And... Nothing...

I deleted the previous package `sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql` and `apt-get --purge remove mysql-server` then reinstalled it like above, same message, and nothing was installed.

when I do `mysql -V` I have `version mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1` and when I do `dpkg -l mysql` I get version `5.5.28`... on phpinfo I got `5.1.63`

Is there a step missing to do this installation ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why should I have a downvote ? I searched during 3 hours on internet for a solution, if you find this question stupid please tell me why.

Comment: What's your "nothing" is? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I don't know what to do to install it after doing `dpkg -i mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb` I supose

Comment: All tutorial doesn't go further than the `dpkg`... I suppose that we need to know but I'm not a linux expert so I can't really guess

Comment: that's right, dpkg is first and last command. You can ensure that package is installed with `apt-cache policy mysql` or `dpkg -l mysql`

Comment: Ok so when I do `mysql -V` I have version `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1` and when I do `dpkg -l mysql` I get version `5.5.28`... on phpinfo I got `5.1.63`

Comment: Maybe you installed a second version (in `/usr/local/`, say) that is reflected in your path.  I happily run mysql and postgresql and several Debian / Ubuntu machines and they all ipgrade themselves just fine via `apt-get` et al.

Comment: I removed everything via `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` and now I can't install it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the previous version, then install the new one from the downloaded .deb.

Comment: I edited my message with the delete